# Is it possible to query the setup tables (Profile/PermssionSet) from SF flow while running the flow as a non admin user?

Tags: visual-workflow

Is it possible to query the setup tables (Profile/PermssionSet) from SF flow while running the flow as a non admin user?
If not, what is the workaround?

I need the Id of some profiles/perm set from the flow and the flow will always be run as some non admin users.
Is hardcoding the Ids my only option or there is a better way to open up Setup object from within flow?

P.S. it is a GET Records on Setup tables only, no update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Profiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm)

> As of Summer ’20 and later, Customer Portal and Partner Portal users can’t access this object.
>
> To view the following settings, assignments, and permissions for standard and custom objects in a specified profile, **the View Setup and Configuration permission is required**.
>
> - Client settings
> - Field permissions
> - Layout assignments
> - Object permissions
> - Permission dependencies
> - Permission set tab settings
> - Permission set group components
> - Record types

[PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm)

> As of Summer ’20 and later, **only users who have one of these permissions can access this object**:
>
> - View Setup and Configuration
> - Manage Session Permission Set Activations
> - Assign Permission Sets
> - Manage Profiles and Permission Sets

As such, if your flow is running in the *user context* - the user's permissions will be taken into account and queries against those objects  will throw errors.

However, in Flows, you can choose to ignore user context and run in the *system* [context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_system_mode.htm&type=5) which will not respect permissions of the running user.

> You can set a flow version to always run in system context, overriding the context it normally runs in. If you choose system context with sharing, the flow respects org-wide default settings, role hierarchies, sharing rules, manual sharing, teams, and territories. **But it doesn’t respect object permissions, field-level access, or other permissions of the running user**.

In that case, any user can query against those objects you identified. You can see the option to set this in `How to Run the Flow` when you go to save the Flow and click on `Show Advanced`.

[image]